# How to schedule "appear offline" in teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I want to set a schedule when Teams automatically sets my status to "Appear offline" - this is to block disturbances but allow critical communication meanwhile.

Any way to do this?

I am open for script options, power apps, or code alike if this is possible :)

I do not mean change status to "Do not disturb" but be able to schedule when a profile is "appearing offline", disregarding (if possible) calendar status changes.